# CrmEntityDataSource To CodeBehind Datareader

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Im jumping into a project using MS Dynamics and a portal plugin, and am in need with a little help.

On the html side I have a `CrmEntityDataSource` which collects 1 record. I need to be able to get certain fields from this CrmEntityDataSource record in the CodeBehind but I don't know how to do this.

Is there a way to cast it to a codeBehind datareader, or something similar so that I can throw the column fields to labels etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use a Enumerator to read the object:

```
IEnumerator e = dataSource.GetEnumerator();
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    object dataobject = e.Current;
}
```

See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9608.dynamics-crm-2011-portal-development-crmentitydatasource.aspx) more information about CrmEntityDataSource.

Comment: Thanks for that Pedro, Ive already come across the page you linked to but it didnt seem to give much info away. Coukd you tekk me how I can make use of the 'dataobject' in your example. For instance I want to grab a certain column and send that info to a label on the html side.